# Can I state a use case as a precondition for another?

Tags: uml, use-case

I have a use case describing the following:
`The actor can view the table of listings.`
and I want to create another use case where `the actor can delete a listing`.
I consider viewing the table of listings a precondition in order to be able to delete any listings, so can I include the use case title as a precondition or should I just state that `The actor is viewing the listings table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do so by using the `<<include>>` relation:

[image]

Both are stand-alone use cases. `Delete listing` will include `View listings` unconditionally. In the course of actions you will place it in front of the actual deletion in the form of `Perform "View listings"` or the like.

Use cases per se have no order in which they appear. In a few cases you can consider to attach a constraint like `{ Use case X must have been performed once before }`. But that will be rare exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not a great idea.

What happens after you've deleted an item? Can you delete another without listing again?

What if the table contains 120GB of data? Does it still need to be 100% listed before each delete, or even a delete?

What if you discover the item through another end-point, like a search engine, or as a link from another resource. Are you planning on adding them as a pre-condition?

And how would you verify that the collaborator has indeed called that behaviour first?